# CosmosDB: Can't create more than 25 containers in a shared database

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I used to create a Cosmos database with shared throughput that has more than 30 containers. It looks like Microsoft added a limitation in February of this year so that the maximum number of containers in a shared database is 25. My account was given an exception to the rule so I can continue to create more than 25 containers, but I need to migrate my application & data to another Azure account. Thus, I can no longer do what I did before.

This frustrates me because the lowest throughput on an individual container in a non-shared database seems to be 400. Now, I have to pay for `400 * {# of containers}` throughput instead of `100 * {# of containers}`. All that buzz about paying for what you use in a cloud environment seems like a joke now.

I need to know if there is a way to create a container with 100 min throughput?

Comment: I guess just creating another database is not an option for you? You could create one database with shared throughput for every 4 containers. This is the corresponding announcement by the way: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cosmos-db-25-container-limit/

Comment: Never thought of doing that before, but I can indeed create multiple databases!

Comment: One question though.. Is it possible to convert a shared container to a dedicated container in the future? Right now, the only reason I'm using a shared database is to reduce the total cost because I can't afford to pay for 400 RUs per container, but the future might be different.

Comment: It is not possible as far as I know, most changes like this need a full data migration to a new container. E.g. with the import tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data. You can up the throughput on the database quite a lot, but it might be inefficient if just one of your containers requires a lot more load than the rest.

Comment: I think you're right. I just found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput. It says the shared/dedicated throughput option is set only when creating a container. Now that I have to think about multiple dbs, I wonder if I should cap container count at a lower number (e.g. 10) instead of 25. Would this be a better approach than going with the 25 max limit?

Comment: I would not max out the container count unless I had a very good reason for it. 10-15 sounds fine, but it depends heavily on your requirements. I'll write up a quick summary of all of this as an answer so you can resolve the question if you want, or write up an answer of your own if you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer possible to share your database throughput across more than 25 containers. [This is the corresponding announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cosmos-db-25-container-limit/).

> This will allow for better throughput sharing across collections.

To get back to 100 RUs per container, you should just create an additional database with its own [shared troughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#comparison-of-models). I would not recomment to max out each database with 25 containers each just to save costs. It would probably give you a bit more flexibility to only put 10 to 15 containers in one database.

Keep in mind that you will not be able to simply change a collection from shared throughput to dedicated throughput. This is a destructive operation and requires a data migration, e.g. via the [import tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).